# How to delete a Partition in unmanaged delta lake table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

How to delete a Partition in unmanaged/external delta lake table?

```
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName("country_people")
val partitionColumn = "country"
val partitionValue = "Argentina"
```

```
// Delete the partition data
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/country_people")
deltaTable.delete(condition = expr(s"$partitionColumn = '$partitionValue'"))
val retentionHours = 0 // Set the retention period to 0 hours to remove all deleted files
deltaTable.vacuum(retentionHours)
```

Will it be enough or do we also need to use
`dbutils.fs.rm("<your-storage-path>", true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just enough to perform delete operation on partition, then vacuum should remove all referenced files. It's better not to use `dbutils.fs.rm` as you may corrupt the table.